# How to connect simple Formik form with Redux store and dispatch an action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, formik

I'm new at react/redux, but can realize some simple addProduct form for my app. 
Today I tried to replace it with [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) from this [Basic demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zKrK5YLDZ), but I cant't understand where should I place "dispatch" function (I tried it to everywhere).

May be I use connect in wrong way?

My new component is exactly like in [Demo](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik), except I replaced email with productName (and other additional fields). But I can't understand how to pass "values" from Formik to Redux store.

My old form component, without Formik, looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addProduct } from '../actions';

const AddProduct0 = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let inputSKUNumber;
  let inputProductName;
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        ref={(node) => {
          inputSKUNumber = node;
        }}
        placeholder="SKU Number"
      />
      <input
        ref={(node) => {
          inputProductName = node;
        }}
        placeholder="Product name"
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch(addProduct({ SKUNumber: inputSKUNumber.value, name: inputProductName.value }));
          inputSKUNumber.value = '';
          inputProductName.value = '';
        }}
      >
        Add Product
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
const AddProduct = connect()(AddProduct0);

export default AddProduct;
```

My new component with formik looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withFormik } from 'formik';
import Yup from 'yup';
import { addProduct } from '../actions';
import './helper.css';

// Our inner form component. Will be wrapped with Formik({..})
const MyInnerForm = (props) => {
  const {
    values,
    touched,
    errors,
    dirty,
    isSubmitting,
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    handleSubmit,
    handleReset,
  } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="SKUNumber">SKU Number</label>
      <input
        id="SKUNumber"
        placeholder="SKU Number"
        type="number"
        value={values.SKUNumber}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        className={errors.SKUNumber && touched.SKUNumber ? 'text-input error' : 'text-input'}
      />
      <div className="input-feedback">{touched.SKUNumber ? errors.SKUNumber : ''}</div>

      <label htmlFor="productName">Product Name</label>
      <input
        id="productName"
        placeholder="Product Name"
        type="text"
        value={values.productName}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        className={errors.productName && touched.productName ? 'text-input error' : 'text-input'}
      />
      <div className="input-feedback">{touched.productName ? errors.productName : ''}</div>


      <button
        type="button"
        className="outline"
        onClick={handleReset}
        disabled={!dirty || isSubmitting}
      >
        Reset
      </button>
      <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
        Submit
      </button>

      <DisplayFormikState {...props} />
    </form>
  );
};

const EnhancedForm = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: () => ({
    SKUNumber: 12345678,
    productName: 'Default Product',
  }),

  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    SKUNumber: Yup.number()
      .max(99999999, 'SKU Number must be less than 8 digits')
      .required('SKU Number is required!'),

    productName: Yup.string()
      .min(5, 'Product name must be longer than 5 symbols')
      .max(50, 'Product name must be shorter than 50 symbols')
      .required('Product name is required!'),

  handleSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      setSubmitting(false);
    }, 1000);
    // dispatch(addProduct(values));
  },
  displayName: 'BasicForm', // helps with React DevTools
})(MyInnerForm);

export const DisplayFormikState = props => (
  <div style={{ margin: '1rem 0' }}>
    <h3 style={{ fontFamily: 'monospace' }} />
    <pre
      style={{
        background: '#f6f8fa',
        fontSize: '.65rem',
        padding: '.5rem',
      }}
    >
      <strong>props</strong> = {JSON.stringify(props, null, 2)}
    </pre>
  </div>
);

const AddProduct = connect()(EnhancedForm);

export default AddProduct;
```

p.s. If someone have reputation here to add tag "formik", please, do it.

Comment: Dispatch is a method controlled by redux, the second parameter of the connect function is a method that maps the actions to the component props and THAT function is passed dispatch. See below for an example code

Comment: Note that I combined your export and connect lines into one statement, renaming the functional component to AddProduct. It appears you added the 0 for brevity's sake rather than trying to come up with another name for it. However, based on the code in the component this isn't necessary. If this helps, please mark the answer as correct. :) PS: Formik can't be added as tag because there is a maximum of five tags.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I also opened an issue on formik page. And there one of contributors gave me the answer. All works with that code:

```js
handleSubmit(values, { props, setSubmitting }) {
    props.dispatch(addProduct(values));
    setSubmitting(false);
  },
```

Comment: @ShamseerAhammed now is better to use hooks:
`import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'`
(then, in component:)
`const dispatch = useDispatch()`
Or check out, that your redux store is connected to app in a right way. Also check mapDispatchToProps, and connect(...)

Answer (score 0):

```html
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addProduct } from '../actions';

/* AddProduct не совсем контейнер, он просто вызывает диспатч,
  ему не нужен стор, поэтому мы можем создать коннект коротким путем:
  AddProduct = connect()(AddProduct); */
const AddProduct = ({ addMyProduct }) => {
  let inputSKUNumber;
  let inputProductName;
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        ref={(node) => {
          inputSKUNumber = node;
        }}
        placeholder="SKU Number"
      />
      <input
        ref={(node) => {
          inputProductName = node;
        }}
        placeholder="Product name"
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          addMyProduct({ SKUNumber: inputSKUNumber.value, name: inputProductName.value });
          inputSKUNumber.value = '';
          inputProductName.value = '';
        }}
      >
        Add Product
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    addMyProduct: (params) => dispatch(addProduct(params))
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddProduct);
```

Comment: Joshua, this part of code was working how it  is. About question: I can't understand how to improve it with Formik plugin.

Comment: My apologies I misunderstood the question

Comment: Joshua, sorry , it's me, didn't explain clear :( 
Now I added new version of component. and I hope it's easier to  understand , what about I'm talking. May be you know the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a higher variable or async function. Higher variable is a little bit lame but working.

```
let setSubmittingHigher;
// Our inner form component. Will be wrapped with Formik({..})
const MyInnerForm = (props) => {enter code here

.
.
.

    handleSubmit(values, {props, setSubmitting}) {
        setSubmittingHigher = setSubmitting;

.
.
.

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    typeof setSubmittingHigher === 'function' && setSubmittingHigher(false);
    return {}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    addMyProduct: (params) => dispatch(addProduct(params))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddProduct);
```

Comment: or you can try this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/56888802/1778834