# How to run setSubmitting() outside the submit handler?

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware, formik

I'm trying to implement the approach described on  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gl3cCB_26M, where all Redux actions are just plain objects (as they were meant to be) and API calls are done by middlewares.

By doing this, the dispatched actions are no longer thunks and can't return a `Promise`. So I won't be able to use Formik's `setSubmitting` (to set the `isSubmitting` flag to `false`) inside the submit handler, like the code samples on Formik docs and other tutorials I've found.

I've solved the issue in a kinda ugly way, saving a reference of `setSubmitting` to run it later, inside `componentDidUpdate`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

import LoginForm from 'path/to/LoginForm'
import validationSchema from 'path/to/LoginForm/validationSchema'

import { login } from 'path/to/actionCreators'

const initialValues = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
}

class LoginPage extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { auth } = this.props

    if (!auth.isProcessing && this.setSubmitting) {
      this.setSubmitting(false)
    }
  }

  onSubmit = (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    const { dispatch } = this.props

    dispatch(login(values)))
    this.setSubmitting = setSubmitting
  }

  render() {
    const { auth } = this.props
    if (auth.user.uid) {
      return <Redirect push to="/" />
    }

    return (
      <div className="login-panel">
        <h1>Login</h1>

        <Formik
          initialValues={initialValues}
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
          render={LoginForm}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginPage)
```

How can I do it in a more "elegant" way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could implement callbacks. Just invoke an `onSuccess` or `onError` callback in your middleware and handle them in your component.

```js
// component.js
class LoginPage extends Component {

  // ...

  onSubmit = (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    const { dispatch } = this.props

    setSubmitting(true);
    dispatch(
      login(
        values,
        () => setSubmitting(false), // success callback to be invoked in middleware
        (message) => { // error handler invoked in middleware catch
          this._handleErrorMessage(message);
          setSubmitting(false);
        },
      )
    );
  }


}

// actions.js
function loginAction(payload, onSuccess, onError) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN,
    payload,
    onSuccess,
    onError,
  }
}

// middleware.js
function handleLogin(action) {
  const { payload, onSuccess, onError } = action;
  try {
    // login...
    onSuccess('hurray!');
  } catch(error) {
    const { message } = error;
    onError(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Just did a little tweak, putting the callbacks inside a `meta` attribute, to make the action [FSA compliant](https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action).

Comment: @MatheusGomes Nice! I like that idea.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach is by using [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) on to the `<Formik/>` component *(released in React 16.3)*

```
class NewComponent extends Component {
  formikRef = React.createRef()

  render() {
    <Formik
      ref={this.formikRef}
      ..
      ..
    />
  }

  onButtonClick() {
    this.formikRef.current.setSubmitting(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: In the latest version `ref` will not work instead user `innerRef`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59459395/6613333

Answer (score 6):

If the Formik component could accept `isSubmitting` as prop, then it could be implemented much more elegantly. Right now it doesn't (see [source](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/85d15b302cd776eb615064a4451e1a7575b1439d/src/types.tsx#L172-L215)). This would be a great feature request to the Formik team.