# React-Native: Formik ref fails to get value

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, formik

I have a dummy Login code with formik form in react-native

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  TextInput,
  Text,
  Alert,
  Image,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView
} from "react-native";
import styles from "./Styles/LoginStylesheet";
import { KeyboardAccessoryNavigation } from "react-native-keyboard-accessory";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import schemaObject, { initialValues, refs } from "./Validations/LoginValidations";

export default class LoginView extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeInputIndex: 0
    };
  }

  handleFocus = index => () => {
    this.setState({
      activeInputIndex: index
    });
  };

  handleFocusNext = () => {
    if (this.state.activeInputIndex + 1 >= refs.length) {
      return;
    }
    refs[this.state.activeInputIndex + 1].focus();
  };

  handleFocusPrevious = () => {
    if (this.state.activeInputIndex - 1 < 0) {
      return;
    }
    refs[this.state.activeInputIndex - 1].focus();
  };

  handleLogin = () => {
    console.log("ACTIOn");
      // this.formik.handleSubmit();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.safeAreaView}>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaView}>
          <ScrollView style={styles.superView}>
            <Formik {/* LINE 56  */}
              initialValues={initialValues}
              onSubmit={values => Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(values))}
              validationSchema={schemaObject}
              ref={p => (this.formik = p)}
            >
              {({
                values,
                handleChange,
                errors,
                setFieldTouched,
                touched,
                isValid,
                handleSubmit
              }) => (
                <View style={styles.superView}>
                  <View style={styles.logoParentView}>
                    <Image
                      source={require("../../Resources/Assets/Login/aptihealth_logo.png")}
                      resizeMode={"contain"}
                      style={styles.logo}
                    />
                  </View>

                  <View style={styles.emailParentView}>
                    <Text style={styles.titleLabel}>Email Id</Text>
                    <TextInput
                      value={values.emailId}
                      onChangeText={handleChange("emailId")}
                      onBlur={() => setFieldTouched("emailId")}
                      placeholder="Email Id"
                      style={styles.textInput}
                      autoCorrect={false}
                      onFocus={this.handleFocus(0)}
                      ref={input => {
                        refs[0] = input;
                      }}
                    />
                    {touched.emailId && errors.emailId && (
                      <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: "red" }}>
                        {errors.emailId}
                      </Text>
                    )}
                  </View>

                  <View style={styles.passwordParentView}>
                    <Text style={styles.titleLabel}>Password</Text>
                    <TextInput
                      value={values.password}
                      onChangeText={handleChange("password")}
                      placeholder="Password"
                      onBlur={() => setFieldTouched("password")}
                      style={styles.textInput}
                      autoCorrect={false}
                      secureTextEntry={true}
                      onFocus={this.handleFocus(1)}
                      ref={input => {
                        refs[1] = input;
                      }}
                    />
                    {touched.password && errors.password && (
                      <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: "red" }}>
                        {errors.password}
                      </Text>
                    )}
                  </View>

                  <View style={styles.forgotPasswordParentView}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      style={styles.forgotpasswordButton}
                      activeOpacity={0.7}
                    >
                      <Text>Forgot Password?</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>

                  <View style={styles.loginParentView}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() => {
                        console.log("VALUES: ", values, this.formik);
                        this.handleLogin();
                      }}
                      style={styles.loginButton}
                      activeOpacity={0.7}
                    >
                      <Text style={styles.loginText}>Login</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>

                  <View style={styles.seperaterParentView}>
                    <View style={styles.seperaterView} />
                    <Text style={styles.seperaterText}>OR</Text>
                    <View style={styles.seperaterView} />
                  </View>

                  <View style={styles.faceIdLoginParentView}>
                    <Image
                      source={require("../../Resources/Assets/face_id_small_color/face_id_small_color.png")}
                      resizeMode={"contain"}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.faceIdButton}>
                      <Text>Sign In with Face ID</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.signUpParentView}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.signupButton}>
                      <Text>Sign Up for Account Here</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                </View>
              )}
            </Formik>
          </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
        <KeyboardAccessoryNavigation
          nextDisabled={false}
          previousDisabled={false}
          nextHidden={false}
          previousHidden={false}
          onNext={this.handleFocusNext}
          onPrevious={this.handleFocusPrevious}
          avoidKeyboard
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to console formik ref in login action getting undefined value with debug error

```
ExceptionsManager.js:126 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `LoginView`.
    in Formik (at LoginView.js:56)
```

I have no idea why it's getting undefined ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1603).

You problem is here

```
<Formik
  initialValues={initialValues}
  onSubmit={values => Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(values))}
  validationSchema={schemaObject}
  ref={p => (this.formik = p)} {/* passing this ref will throw the error */}
>
```

In the latest version of Formik, they changed Formik to a functional component as explained in the issue, which gives you this error if you pass ref's.

You can check for the suggestions on the issue or wait until they release an update with the correction.

## Edit:

Formik made an update and now you can use ref with the prop `innerRef`.

Please see [this comment](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1603#issuecomment-575669249)

You should change it to

```
<Formik
  initialValues={initialValues}
  onSubmit={values => Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(values))}
  validationSchema={schemaObject}
  {/* using innerRef instead of ref*/}
  innerRef={p => (this.formik = p)} {/* this will give you the formik bag */}
>
```

And this way you can call `this.formik.handleSubmit()`, just lik you want to do.