# Using Redux Hooks in a Formik onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, formik

i am currently trying to solve a homework for my university.

We should integrate Action Creators and Reducers to our react project.

The project is about having a Money Transaction Form with a List which shows all money transactions.

[Image of the Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQWxz.png)

We built the form with help of formik, my code looks like this.

```
const formik = useFormik({
initialValues: { ownwho: '', username: '', amount: '' },
validationSchema: validationSchema,
onSubmit: values => dispatch(createMoneyTransaction(1,2,3))
})
```

The Form is a normal form, with a handleSubmit and handleChange

```
<form className={styles.moneytransaction_form} onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
  <div className={styles.radio_wrapper}>
    <div>
      <label>I owe somebody</label>
      <Input type='radio' name='ownwho' value='IOweYou' onChange={formik.handleChange} />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Somebody owes me</label>
      <Input type='radio' name='ownwho' value='YouOweMe' onChange={formik.handleChange} />
    </div>
  </div>
```

My Dispatch is currently looking like that

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
```

Action Creator

[Image of the Action Creator for the Post Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d1eV.png)

Now i have the following problem.

When using the dispatch hook inside of the formik onsubmit handle i get this error by react

[Image of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlrTM.png)

I do think it is because the hook does have to be in a functional component and formik may not be one.

I would really be happy if someone can help me out on this one, because i dont fully understand what the problem about the usage of this hook with formik is.

Comment: Wrap your form in a redux form so you can use the form store to dispatch any form action?

Comment: @DanysChalifour we do need to use formik, so we cant just wrap a redux form around it

Comment: see for ref ;https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420358/how-to-connect-simple-formik-form-with-redux-store-and-dispatch-an-action 
Are you sure your store is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not following the rule of hooks (in this case, `useDispatch()` is the hook). Either because you are not calling the hook in the right place or because you might be calling it conditionally or from something that is not a functional component.